# How to get hyperlinks placed inside of shapes in .docx file using office interop word

Tags: c#, .net, hyperlink, ms-word, office-interop

I’m looking for a way to programmatically replace hyperlinks from inside of word documents. I already have code which handles hyperlinks replacement as long as those’re placed along document’s main text. Unfortunately this code doesn’t see hyperlinks if those’re placed inside of shapes. The documents I deal with quite often contains diagrams (flow-charts) composed of shapes (often grouped shapes) and I can’t find any way to retrieve and modify hyperlinks from inside of the shapes.

The code that I’ve so far allows me to retrieve all hyperlinks from documents text:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application applicationObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDDoc = applicationObject.Documents.Open(FileName: @"c:\Temp\a.docx");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlinks links = aDDoc.Hyperlinks;

foreach (var hyperlink in links)
        {
            string adress = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink) hyperlink).Address;
        }
```

Unfortunately all the attempts to retrieve hyperlinks from shape object cause an exception:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shapes shapes = aDDoc.Shapes;


        foreach (var shape in shapes)
        {

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink hyperlink = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape)shape).Hyperlink;

                string adress = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink)hyperlink).Address;
        }
```

This throws an exception on line where address variable is assigned. I’m working in non-English version of visual studio so the exception I get is also not in English but it says something like: operation could not be performed

Anyone have an idea how to retrieve hyperlinks from inside of shapes?

Comment: Improved my answer. Now you may even have groups in groups with shapes and you will still get access to any hyperlinks. Please consider voting up my answer if my effort was of any help for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a small example which retrieves hyperLinks from shapes within a word file. I am working with Word 2010. You cannot access a text hyperlink from within a shape by `Shape.Hyperlink` as this will get you

> Returns a Hyperlink object that represents the hyperlink associated
>   with the specified shape.

see [MSDN - Shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape_members(v=office.14).aspx) documentation.

Instead of this you have to access the **Shape - TextFrame - TextRange** property. This will allow you access to hyperlinks in the text of any shape.

**Source Code**

```
/// entry point - will look for hyperlinks in text
/// and afterwards in shapes within this document
private static void replaceHyperlinksInShapes()
{
    Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(FileName: @"e:\Temp\demoFile.docx");
    Word.Hyperlinks links = doc.Hyperlinks;

    Debug.WriteLine("Text Hyperlinks");
    foreach (var hyperlink in links)
    {
        string address = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink)hyperlink).Address;
        Debug.WriteLine("\t" + address);
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Shape Hyperlinks");
    foreach (Word.Shape shape in doc.Shapes)
    {
        searchForHyperLink(shape);
    }
}

/// will search for hyperlinks in given shape
/// if this shape is a group, call recursivly
private static void searchForHyperLink(Word.Shape shape)
{
    /// check if this shape is a group or not
    /// CRUCIAL!!! There are way more types which may contain hyperlinks
    /// check if necessary
    if (shape.Type == Office.MsoShapeType.msoAutoShape)
    {
        Word.TextFrame frame = shape.TextFrame;
        Word.Range range = frame.TextRange;
        if (range != null)
        {
            foreach (var hyperlink in range.Hyperlinks)
            {
                string address = ((Word.Hyperlink)hyperlink).Address;
                Debug.WriteLine("\t" + address);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (shape.Type == Office.MsoShapeType.msoGroup)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= shape.GroupItems.Count; i++)
        {
            Word.Shape childShape = shape.GroupItems[i];
            searchForHyperLink(childShape);
        }
    }
}
```

**Word-File**

[image: sample file with a hyperlink in text and one in a shape]

**Result output**

[image: result for the given word file and provided source]

**Edit**

After searching around in MSDN I tumbled accros [Type Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.type(v=office.14).aspx). By using this one I was able to differ between shapes and groups (*a group is a shape too!*).

I hope this will be of any help for you!

Comment: It works great for individual shapes but crashes when there’re groups of shapes inside of document. Can you show me how to push it one step further to take care of grouped shapes as well?

Comment: I am working on it, I already can access text/links in groups, but still have problems accessing/managing groups in groups - I'll post here when I had time to look into it